# Where is the azure notification hubs node sdk usage documentation?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Obviously Stack Overflow is not the place for this question, but twitter @azuresupport refuses to do anything other than tell people to post here with a tag. So here goes.

Where the #$%@ are the node sdk docs? They used to be in google cache, and now they aren't even there. There are multiple issues in the github asking for the docs. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/2291

Comment: The link in a [short tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial) does indeed point to the [Git repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node). You can always click on the Wiki in Github and see if any of the other documentation helps you out.

Comment: The git repo links to here for the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nodejs/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-node-2.2.0  but this is only the "management" docs, no usage docs exist anywhere. They used to exist here: https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/global.html

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Archive still has a cached copy at https://web.archive.org/web/20170107075814/https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-sb/latest/global.html

Comment: Apparently MS is relying on this for the time being as they are directing to it on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

The docs were inadvertently removed from the doc repo, and we are working to resurrect them. We're sorry about that and will comment here when they're back.

Thank you for your patience,

Karl